# Проблема с OpenVPN

Tags: linux, openvpn, router, mikrotik

Есть роутер (mikrotik) и на нем настроены pptp и openvpn сервер. При подключении к pptp я получаю доступ ко всем ресурсам сети. А вот если я подключаюсь к openvpn доступа к ресурсам нет. После подключения я проверяю шлю роутера и он доступен. Прошу помощи разобраться.

Comment: можете показать: а) конфиг openvpn и б) route -n (или route print) на клиентской машине

Comment: port - 1194
mode - ip
max mtu - 1500
keepalive - 60
certificate - mycert.crt
default profile - ppp (я создавал)

Comment: 0.0.0.0         192.168.198.2   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
    192.168.91.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
    192.168.198.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

Comment: @JamesMaynard Редактируйте вопрос, зачем в комментариях писать, то что относится к вопросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

разобрался дело было в конфиге подключения, не хватало 3х комманд.

```
redirect-gateway def1
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.91.1
```

Comment: Достаточно redirect-gateway def1. 
Без route